# iterate over QMap starting from given key

Tags: qt, iterator, functor, qmap

I have a qmap list,

```
 map.insert(1,"One");
 map.insert(2,"Two");
 map.insert(3,"Three");
 map.insert(4,"Four");
map.insert(5,"five");
map.insert(5.5,"five.five");
map.insert(7,"five.five");
```

my interval is [2,5.1]
I need to start  from 2 till i reach  5

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterators returned from [`lowerBound`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmap.html#lowerBound-2) and [`upperBound`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmap.html#upperBound-2) to do this:

```
QMap<double, QString>::const_iterator lower = map.lowerBound(2);
QMap<double, QString>::const_iterator upper = map.upperBound(5.1);

for ( ; lower != upper; ++lower)
{
    qDebug() << *lower;
}
```